# Fullcalendar event function callback, "unidentified is not a function"

Tags: jquery, angularjs, fullcalendar

Im on the last step of implementing a JSON feed into my Fullcalendar and I am having issues with the callback function. I keep getting the errors "unidentified is not a function" or "unexpected identifier" depending on where I put the "callback(event)" function.

Here's the entire Ajax request:

```
App.controller('calCtrl', function ($scope, $log, $state) {

    $scope.eventSources = [{

        events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {

            $.ajax({

                url: 'url/calendarConnect.php',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(response) {

                    var event = [];
                    $(response).find('events').each(function() {

                        event.push({
                                title: $(this).attr('title'),
                                start: $(this).attr('start'),
                                end: $(this).attr('end')
                        });

                    });

                }  

            });

            callback(event);

        }

    }]

});
```

Any ideas on what the problem is would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The callback will definitely need to be within the ajax success function, and the reason you're getting undefined errors is probably that you haven't passed in a function to be used as the callback.

Comment: and how would I go about doing this, my experience with fullcalendar, and angular are extremely limited

Comment: never heard of fullcalendar myself. I recommend working through the official angular tutorial and using its own $http/$resource rather than $.ajax.

Comment: i'd like to but fullcalendar is a jquery based calendar that works perfectly for what I need, I am using a modified version to allow it to work in AngularJS for the cordova app I am working on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move 'callback' into the success function of your ajax request.  I'm assuming you don't want the callback to be called unless the ajax request succeeds.  Also, you won't have a reference to the 'event' variable if the callback is outside of the function.

```
success: function(response) {
  var event = [];
  $(response).find('events').each(function() {
    event.push({
      title: $(this).attr('title'),
      start: $(this).attr('start'),
      end: $(this).attr('end')
    });
  });

callback(event);

}
```

Comment: This was the solution however now I am getting an empty array when I log "event" in the console, "response" is getting the JSON object. Any thoughts?

Comment: never mind, with some tweaking of the success function I figured it out and it is now working